# Unable to pass a 2D char array in C (only first index seems to be passed)

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Here's a chunk of the function I wrote. File[120][80], an array of lines and characters, is passed in.

```
void Print(char File[120][80], int Lines, char* COMMAND) {
    //Print whole file.
    if (!spaces(COMMAND)) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i<Lines; i++) {
            printf("%i===%s", i+1, File[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of running it (for a 4-line file) is:

```
1===Line 1.
2===3===4===
```

So it seems only the first index is actually being passed.

Comment: Seems the other strings are empty.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: This code is correct(http://ideone.com/ljd22). The problem must lie with your code to read the file.

Comment: The file is read with fgetc. I checked in main(), and the array is properly populated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in how you are calling `Print` or initializing the array you pass -- if I add the following, it works just fine for me:

```
int spaces(const char *s) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    char File[][80] = {
        "Line1\n", "Line2\n", "Line3\n", "Line4\n"
    };
    Print(File, 4, "test");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm calling it as Print(File, Lines, COMMAND);. The array is defined as char File[120][80];.

Comment: How do you initialize `File`?

Comment: Well, then it doesn't contain anything, so its not suprising that the print routine doesn't print anything...

Comment: It's populated later on, and I can successfully check the contents from main().

Comment: @Alexandra `char File[120][80];` is a _declaration_ not an _initialization_. The code where it is "populated later on" would most likely be your _initialization_. That is the code that Chris wants to see.